# Balloon Popup Extender not visible at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i am working on a webpage ,on that i have some fields and through that want to generate balloon popup on hover.The build is getting successful but the balloon popup is not visible at run time please help.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <table><tr><td>First Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtfirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Middle Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtmiddlename" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtlast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>      
        </table>       
        <cc1:BalloonPopupExtender ID="BalloonPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtfirst" BalloonPopupControlID="pan1" BalloonSize="Medium" BalloonStyle="Rectangle" DisplayOnMouseOver="true" UseShadow="true">
        </cc1:BalloonPopupExtender>
        <cc1:BalloonPopupExtender ID="BalloonPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtmiddlename" BalloonPopupControlID="pan2" BalloonSize="Small" BalloonStyle="Cloud" DisplayOnMouseOver="true" >
        </cc1:BalloonPopupExtender>
        <cc1:BalloonPopupExtender ID="BalloonPopupExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtlast" BalloonPopupControlID="pan3" UseShadow="true" DisplayOnFocus="true" CustomClassName="oval" CustomCssUrl="~/CSS/Custom.css">
        </cc1:BalloonPopupExtender>    
          <asp:Panel ID="pan1" runat="server">
    Enter your First Name
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pan2" runat="server">
    Enter your Middle Name
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pan3" runat="server">
    Enter your Last Name
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We will need to see some code/error message to be able to help you.

Comment: i had already attached the ajax dll too...and also the <%--%> text

Comment: Is there any Error in My code.please let me know thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the HTML code, it looks like you are missing a tag that allow you to use the balloon stuff.

include the following after the form tag;

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkit1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>.
```

I am not familiar with the library you are using but this link may help if the above doesn't work.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/409451/how-to-use-balloonpopupextender-ajax